# AutoComplete for MediaPipe Library in VS Code

Tags: python

I am writing a program to detect Hands Gesture in Real-Time using the MediaPipe Library in Python on Visual Studio Code (V.S. Code). But, I am not getting the auto-complete suggestions while writing my Code for the same. Any suggestions which extensions will be helpful in providing me with the same? Appreciate your help:)

```
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mp_hands.Hands()
mp_draw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
```

Answer (score 6):

I changed mp.solutions.hands to mp.solutions.mediapipe.python.solutions.hands and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, for "drawing_utilities", you can use :
**mp.solutions.mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).